# Catch RPC Server Unavailable Error HRESULT: 0x800706BA

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

In powershell, I can catch Access is Denied error using Catch [System.UnauthorizedAccessException]. How do I similarly catch RPC Server Unavailable error?

Comment: I think this is the error with more details: 

`Get-WmiObject : The RPC server is unavailable. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800706BA)
At C:\Users\flickerfly\Documents\scripts\Set-LocalServerAdmin.ps1:22 char:33
+       $oldexists = Get-WmiObject <<<<  Win32_UserAccount -Filter "Name='$olduser'" -ComputerName $computerName
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Get-WmiObject], COMException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : GetWMICOMException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetWmiObjectCommand`

Answer (score 5):

If you add the common parameter -ErrorAction Stop to the, in my case, get-wmiobject command it will cause the command to respond to this non-terminating error as a terminating error and drop it to catch for action.

Here is the code I'm using for this purpose. I probably should be more specific in the catch, but it works for now.

```
# Is this machine on network?, if not, move to next machine
If (!(Test-Connection -ComputerName $computerName -Count 1 -Quiet)) { 
  Write-Host "$computerName not on network."
  Continue # Move to next computer
}

# Does the local Administrator account exist? Returns a string if it exists, which is true-ish.
try {

  $filter = "Name='$olduser' AND Domain='$computerName'"
  $account = Get-WmiObject Win32_UserAccount -Filter $filter -ComputerName $computerName -ErrorAction Stop

} catch {

  Write-Warning "$computerName Can't check for accounts, likely RPC server unavailable"
  Continue # Move to next computer

} #end try
```

Comment: What do you write in $olduser variable? Loacl administrator user name?

Comment: The script this was a part of was changing usernames for admin accounts I believe. $olduser was the name of the user account I was changing to another username. So $olduser would have probably been "Administrator".  $account would then be the "Administrator" account object if one existed. If not, it would then not include a user object and clearly not needing any attention. (It's been awhile, but I think that's how it worked.)

Comment: It seems the RPC Server Unavailable error does not get caught by default, hence the OP's question, perhaps (or, *my* issue :) But adding -ErrorAction Stop to my GWMI does the trick, thank you.

Answer (score 4):

You can catch every exception you want. Just write:

```
$_.Exception.GetType()
```

inside your catch to see what exception is there and then catch it.