# Try-Catch cannot catch non-terminating error 'hresult'

Tags: windows, powershell, iis, try-catch, iis-8

I need to catch the follow error that is currently being outputted:

> ERROR ( hresult:80070425, message:Command execution failed.) The
>   service cannot accept control messages at this time.

From my PowerShell script snippet, which is not catching the error currently:

```
Try{
    appcmd start apppool /apppool.name:DefaultAppPool
}Catch{
    #$ErrorMessage = $_.Exception.Message
    #$FailedItem = $_.Exception.ItemName
    Write-Host "AppPool cannot start." -BackgroundColor Red
}
```

Am I missing something? I would like the error message to be as specific as possible. If it helps, this is IIS8.5. I've referenced these links: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33456028/powershell-try-catch-not-working) | [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39300279/powershell-try-catch-is-not-working-on-below-code) | [3](http://www.vexasoft.com/blogs/powershell/7255220-powershell-tutorial-try-catch-finally-and-error-handling-in-powershell) | [4](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847793.aspx) | [5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8086357/catch-rpc-server-unavailable-error-hresult-0x800706ba) |

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Try/catch does not seem to have an effect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1142211/try-catch-does-not-seem-to-have-an-effect)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message you get probably comes from the `appcmd` thus is *not* a [powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell) exception which you can catch. You may check the `$global:LastExitCode` to verfiy whether the call was successfull.

However, there is also a `WebAdministration` [powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell) module which has a `Start-WebAppPool` cmdlet:

```
Import-Module WebAdministration
Start-WebAppPool -Name 'DefaultAppPool'
```

Comment: thanks for the explanation. Is this cmdlet able to return a result as appcmd? On appcmd, I'm also attempting to throw some custom errors to see if any works.

Comment: I am not familiar with appcmd but the `Start-WebAppPool` also outputs an error message **and** you can use a *try-catch* to catch any exceptions. But whether the message is similar to the one from appcmd I can't tell you.